# USB Communication, Read Message with Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, usb

I'm having an issue playing something with USB communication. I'm  using [HidLibrary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HidLibrary/) library, which works beautifully. The only thing that doesn't work is timeout (I already looked on web for a solution but this is a library bug). So, when I send a message and no response comes to PC, my loop runs forever. I am just waiting for bool is message is readed with success or not. If a message does not come, what then? How I can solve that? With multithreading ([WaitHandle class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle(v=vs.110).aspx)) or are there any alternatives?

Comment: Can you show a code sample of the call you're making to HidLibrary?

Comment: Its open source, you could take a jab at fixing the bug yourself rather than work around it.

Comment: I found solution: _device.OpenDevice(DeviceMode.Overlapped,DeviceMode.Overlapped,ShareMode.Exclusive); Only problem is that device is Opened by default but not over this conditions which I want :) So CloseDevice(); and that OpenDevice(...).